# How to know whether channel is sucessfully unsubscribed or not in pubnub for swift?

Tags: swift, xcode, pubnub

I am subscribing to a channel with an enabled presence, but at the server end event is not received, so I want to make sure whether I am able to subscribe and unsubscribe the channel successfully.

```
let listener = SubscriptionListener()

func registerForConnectRoom(roomId: String) {
    print("roomId \(roomId)")
    pubnub.subscribe(to: ["ch:callroom:" + roomId], withPresence: true)
   
    
   listener.didReceiveSubscription = { event in
    
     switch event {
     case let .messageReceived(message):
       print("heuuu \(message)")
     
     
     case let .signalReceived(signal):
        print("Abhay2")
     case let .connectionStatusChanged(status):
        print("Abhay3")
     case let .subscriptionChanged(change):
        print("Abhay4")
     case let .presenceChanged(presence):
        print("Abhay5")
     case let .uuidMetadataSet(metadata):
        print("Abhay6")
     case let .uuidMetadataRemoved(metadataId):
        print("Abhay7")
     case let .channelMetadataSet(metadata):
        print("Abhay8")
     case let .channelMetadataRemoved(channelMetadataId):
        print("Abhay9")
     case let .membershipMetadataSet(membership):
        print("Abhay10")
     case let .membershipMetadataRemoved(membership):
        print("Abhay11")
     case let .messageActionAdded(action):
        print("Abhay12")
     case let .messageActionRemoved(action):
        print("Abhay13")
     case let .fileUploaded(file):
        print("Abhay14")
     case let .subscribeError(error):
        print("Abhay15")
     }
   }
    
   pubnub.add(listener)
}



func unsubscribe(roomId: String) {
    pubnub.unsubscribe(from: ["ch:callroom:" + roomId])
    self.listener.didReceiveSubscription = { event in
     
      switch event {
      case let .messageReceived(message):
        print("heuuu \(message)")
      
      
      case let .signalReceived(signal):
         print("Abhay2")
      case let .connectionStatusChanged(status):
         print("Abhay3")
      case let .subscriptionChanged(change):
         print("Abhay4")
      case let .presenceChanged(presence):
         print("Abhay5")
      case let .uuidMetadataSet(metadata):
         print("Abhay6")
      case let .uuidMetadataRemoved(metadataId):
         print("Abhay7")
      case let .channelMetadataSet(metadata):
         print("Abhay8")
      case let .channelMetadataRemoved(channelMetadataId):
         print("Abhay9")
      case let .membershipMetadataSet(membership):
         print("Abhay10")
      case let .membershipMetadataRemoved(membership):
         print("Abhay11")
      case let .messageActionAdded(action):
         print("Abhay12")
      case let .messageActionRemoved(action):
         print("Abhay13")
      case let .fileUploaded(file):
         print("Abhay14")
      case let .subscribeError(error):
         print("Abhay15")
      }
    }
}
```

when I am subscribing and unsubscribing in both cases the **print("Abhay4")** code block is executed so Am I sucessfully subscribing and unsubscribing the channel?

Comment: Have you tried checking the value of the `change` variable? It probably contains information about the new state of the subscription.

Comment: how can I check that

Comment: Using `print`, breakpoints, etc. That's pretty basic Swift debugging.

Comment: Same as your other post, can we see your code that calls these methods? Please post full code so we can follow the flow. Also, you can just enabled SDK logs, reproduce and submit to PN Support (support@pubnub.com) and include link to this post so we can post answer back here.

Comment: Also, you need to create the listener before you subscribe if you want to see events related to that subscribe. And the unsubscribe is not going to be received by the client that unsubscribed because the client is no longer connected though you might get a "disconnected event" or similar, but not the "leave" presence event.

Comment: Last tip: have you tried the Swift Getting Started? Specifically, this one: https://www.pubnub.com/docs/quickstarts/swift - it is different than this one: https://www.pubnub.com/docs/sdks/swift#configure-pubnub - the first one above might be simpler and easier to understand.

Comment: And final question :) - subscriptionChanged happens when the subscription changes, so that makes sense. When you say "the server end event is not received", where is that code? Your "server" would need to subscribe to that channel "withPresence" or more properly, you server should implement a RESTful webhook to receive [presence webhooks for all channels](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/presence/presence-webhooks).

Comment: You ask question, we ask question to help but never see any response from you. Please provide some follow up so we know if you require further assistance or not. If you resolved the issue on your own, please post your solution as an Answer.